# show option value selected in form select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

my question is really of basic level, but seems like i am unable to figure out how i can do the following.

i have a form inside my view as follows

```
<%= form_for(@admin, :url => {:action => :update}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :Advance_Search_allow, "Allow advance search?" %>
    <%= f.select :Advance_Search_allow, options_for_select(["Yes", "No"]) %>

    <%= f.label :paid_Alert, "Number of alerts to send for Pro Users" %>
    <%= f.text_field :paid_Alert %>

    <%= f.label :basic_Alert, "Number of alerts to send for Basic Users" %>
    <%= f.text_field :basic_Alert %>

    <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

the `:paid_Alert` and `:basic_Alert` are being populated as they are in db. but i am trying to populate select's option with that of the db and providing the other value as it is in shown in code. plz let me know how i can achieve this. 
Pardon me if my question sounds dumb and please point me the link if my question is duplicate. Thanks in Advnce

Comment: Try this: options_for_select([["Yes", 1], ["No", 0]])

Comment: @SatyaKalluri it didn't worked.

Comment: What do you mean by 'populate select's option with that of the db'. My  comment only dealt with populating the select-box with YES & NO options

Comment: i already have some value in db saved. the value that is in db should be selected when page loads. the other value should be in select box for any change that user want to make.

Comment: DO you store the value in the DB as a boolean or String?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42330/discussion-between-satya-kalluri-and-sak)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try
 `options_for_select(["Yes", "No"], @admin.Advance_Search_allow`

Comment: The options_for_select generates thew HTML for the options-tags and it should be notified of the valuer to mark as SELECTED. So, we need to pass it as a parameter.
Lemme know if it helps.

Comment: Checkout the documentation at http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select